# Cron Error on Ubuntu (Command Not Found)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line-interface, cron

Trying to add this to the crontab (Ubuntu):

```
0 2 * * * /usr/local/sbin/aws dsnap | grep vol-193vja9 | sort -r -k 5  | sed 1,5d | awk '{print "Deleting snapshot: " $2 " Dated:" $8}; system("/usr/local/sbin/aws delsnap " $2 )'  >>  /var/backup.log  2>&1
```

However, I'm getting an error that says:

```
0: command not found
```

Comment: Just to be clear, is that the actual command line you are trying to run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could be wrong, but it looks like you are trying to execute the whole crontab job, including the crontab times.

Try adding your crontab job with this:

```
echo "0 2 * * * /usr/local/sbin/aws dsnap | grep vol-193vja9 | sort -r -k 5  | sed 1,5d | awk '{print "Deleting snapshot: " $2 " Dated:" $8}; system("/usr/local/sbin/aws delsnap " $2 )'  >>  /var/backup.log  2>&1" | crontab -
```

However, it would probably be easier for you to just edit the crontab like so:

```
crontab -e
```

and then paste the line into the screen manually.

Either way, you can verify that its been added by typing:

```
[rilindo@kvm0007 ~]$ crontab -l
0 2 * * * /usr/local/sbin/aws dsnap | grep vol-193vja9 | sort -r -k 5  | sed 1,5d | awk '{print Deleting snapshot:    Dated: }; system(/usr/local/sbin/aws delsnap   )'  >>  /var/backup.log  2>&1
```